# SAS Enterprise Guide - Error while executing workspace job. Server disconnected

Tags: sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

So I am only executing a program using proc sql to create a table with statistics on X.

After a while, the task bar says complete, but the table is never created and I have this error poping up.

Any idea where it can come from? I can run other programs just fine so it's specific to that one.

Thanks!

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia0pw.png

Comment: Googling your title shows this might be due to your program generating an abnormally large log. Without the program itself, we can't tell you much more.

Comment: The program is about 1600 lines with 1 big querie of like 800-900 lines. Is there a way to prevent printing parts of the log?

Comment: Well yeah, there's a billion and one options. To start, try putting `options nosource nonotes errors=0;` at the start of your program and see if it runs. If so, figure out what log output you need to keep and go from there.

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately i get the same error.

Comment: Like I said, we're not going to be able to do much without seeing your program. All I'm doing is googling your error message. Try cutting out pieces of it to see exactly what procedure/step is causing the error.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's just as much as I'd like to paste the code, I can't (work for a bank) and it's all private stuff. Don't really want to potentially lose my job over a stupid SAS error hehe. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just figured it out if it helps anybody in the future.

For me, I was adding a new column with conditions like

```
SELECT*
,Case
    WHEN calculated columnX like 'text1' OR
         calculated columnX like 'text2' OR
         calculated columnX like 'text3' 
    THEN result
END AS columnX
FROM TableA
```

but the column after the calculateds should have been columnW. Basically, it was auto-referencing. It didn't gave me an error in the log, and without a debugger, it was quite hard to find.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doing something like that in Display Manager generates an exception and a message in the LOG to tell SAS  technical support about it with a dump of some traceback information.  I suspect that EG (and probably SAS/Studio) is getting confused by the  failure and not returning the log messages to you.